# Match value and put date in new column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
accountName date      orderNumber
A           1/1/2016  1
B           1/2/2016  1
A           1/3/2016  2
A           1/4/2016  3
B           1/5/2016  2
C           1/6/2016  1
A           1/7/2016  4
```

I want to be able to find the number of a person's order, and make a new column with that date of that order and a N/A if it does not apply. I would move along a sequence to find the exact dates for the clients of their nth order.

```
accountName date      orderNumber firstOrderDate  secondOrderDate
A           1/1/2016  1           1/1/2016        N/A
B           1/2/2016  1           1/2/2016        N/A
A           1/3/2016  2           N/A             1/3/2016
A           1/4/2016  3           N/A             N/A
B           1/5/2016  2           N/A             1/5/2016
C           1/6/2016  1           1/6/2016        N/A
A           1/7/2016  4           N/A             N/A
```

I've tried using `match` but I'm getting a result which does not make sense where it is not returning unique values of the df.

```
df[match((df$count), 1), ]
```

I'm not asking on how to get the sequence coded, but how to find the dates corresponding to the order number and put it in a new column.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R:

```
df$firstOrderDate <- with(df, ifelse(orderNumber == 1, date, NA))
```

With dplyr:

```
df %<>% mutate(firstOrderDate = ifelse(orderNumber == 1, date, NA))
```

Comment: I think it should be %>% instead of %<>% ... and the code worked! Thanks!

Comment: Oh, `%<>%` is the `magrittr` operator that replaces `df <- df %>%`, sorry about the unneeded shorthand!

Comment: I had no idea about magrittr! I tried to run your code and I got ```Error: could not find function "%<>%"``` Is it included in dplyr?

Comment: It's not -- you'd need to `library(magrittr)`. If you have `tidyverse` installed, it'll be installed already.

Comment: Great. Thanks agan!